# How to trigger error event in clipboard.js for testing

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

We have success and error event for Clipboard.js. 
I need to test error section in Clipboard.js library. Is there any way to trigger error event with programming.

Comment: Anything you've done so far.

Comment: How are you testing the success event ?